# Can't post ajax value

Tags: ajax, post

Still stack in these code. On any browser desktop working fine, but when try use chrome on my android, can't post value from ajax datastring.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
jQuery(".button").click(function()
{
  
  var product     = jQuery(".products").val().split('|')[0];
var nomortujuan = jQuery(".nomortujuan").val();
var pn = parseFloat(document.getElementById("val[pin]").value);


var dataString = 'method=sendMessage&message='+product+'.'+ nomortujuan+'.'+pn;
  var web = 'ajax.php';

  jQuery.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: web,
data: dataString,
cache: true,
beforeSend: function(html) {
        document.getElementById("hasil").innerHTML = '';
        jQuery(".flash").show();
        jQuery(".flash").html('<div style="float:left;"></div>');
            },

    success: function(html){
    jQuery("#js_process_request input, #js_process_request select").attr('disabled',false);
    jQuery(".flash").hide();
    jQuery("#hasil").hide();
    jQuery ("#hasil").append(html);
    return false;
    }

    });
   });
   });
```

Comment: Your URL is not valid, you need a domain, like: http://www.example.com/ajax.php

Comment: stil not working...bro

Comment: Which info do you get from the developer tools in chrome?

Comment: What means blank page? What do you see under network and do you have tested the site under desktop chrome?

Comment: can u help me or just comment?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem

```
jQuery ("#hasil").append(html);
```

remove spacing to fix it

```
jQuery("#hasil").append(html);
```

Comment: Dont put `return false;` in success ,